# Accessing PHP REST api using D3.js

Tags: php, json, d3.js

Here's part of my PHP that I'm trying to access using d3.js

PHP:

```
<?php
require 'Slim\Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

use Slim\Slim;
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/smthng', 'smthng');

function smthng(){
}
```

I just didn't copy the entire PHP cause I know it works. When I pull the data using backbone using "API/smthng" in the collection, it displays the data fine. I also was able to use the location on the browser to view the data. It returns data in JSON. I just couldn't get the data using d3.js.

I tried:

```
d3.json("http://localhost:81/API/smthng", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(d);
});
```

AND:

```
  d3.json("API/smthng", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            console.log(d);
    });
```

also couple other things that didn't work. How can I access the data? I shouldn't have to create a separate php file only for this, right?

Comment: When you say that it didn't work, what do you mean?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I meant to say other ways to get the data. You know, with "/", without "/", changing the name, location, adding "index.php?smthng". None of these approach gave me the data in d3. But, as I mentioned earlier, I was able to get the data in backbone using "API/smthng". So, I know, there's nothing wrong with PHP and URI

Comment: So I'm assuming that you're getting an error message? You haven't given us any detail on the configuration of the webserver and where the script resides there.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Oops, sorry. I was thinking about mentioning that, but completely forgot. I didn't get any error messages. I also tried this ` if(error){return console.warn(error)}` but nothing shows up on the console. It just doesn't show up anything on the page at all. But if I remove the code where it's accessing data, then anything that's supposed to be displayed shows up. But unfortunately, no errors.

Comment: So do you get anything when you call the URL in the browser directly?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes. I get all the data

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, anything I should try? I do get the data on the browser, but just not using d3.js. How can I read it from the PHP API?

Comment: Well it sounds like it should work, so I don't know. Sorry.